# How can I remove text but keep HTML elements, attributes and attribute values?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

Using XSLT, how can one remove all the text nodes from HTML, but keep the element tags, attribute names, and attribute values?

```
<table id="preserve-this-value">
  <caption>Lose this text node</caption>
```

Transformation:

```
<table id="preserve-this-value">
  <caption></caption>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It copies all nodes (elements, attributes) except text nodes.

Comment: Thanks! That works a charm, but is there a way to keep the closing tag intact? That script returns a void <caption/>, if applied to the my original example HTML.

Comment: Try changing the output method to HTML

Comment: @user1822509, Change `<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>`